# Dynamic Matrix Input in Python

Tags: python, matrix, dynamic

```
raw = input("Enret Number of Raws : ")
cols = input("Enter Number of Cols : ")

obj = []
mat = [[[] for j in range(raw)] for i in range(cols)]
for k in range(2):
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(raw):
            number = int(input("Please Enter Elements of Matrix : "))
            mat[i][j] = number
    obj.append(mat)
    print obj
```

Output:

```
Enret Number of Raws : 2
Enter Number of Cols : 2
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 1:9
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 1:3
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 1:7
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 1:1
[[[9, 3], [7, 1]]]
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 2:8
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 2:2
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 2:4
Please Enter Elements of Matrix 2:6
[[[8, 2], [4, 6]], [[8, 2], [4, 6]]]
```

After appending second Matrix in list, Value of 1st get change.

Comment: You've added the same `mat` to `obj` multiple times. If you want `mat` to be a different list each turn through the iteration, move the `mat = [...]` line inside your outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
raw = input("Enret Number of Raws : ")
cols = input("Enter Number of Cols : ")

obj = []

for k in range(2):
    mat = [[[] for j in range(raw)] for i in range(cols)]


    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(raw):
            number = int(input("Please Enter Elements of Matrix : "))
            mat[i][j] = number
    obj.append(mat)
    print obj
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raw = int(input("Enret Number of Raws : "))

cols = int(input("Enter Number of Cols : "))

mat=[]

for i in range(raw):

   a=[]

   for j in range(cols):

      j=int(input("Enter Number in pocket ["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"]"))

      a.append(j)

   mat.append(a)

print(mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

First read total number of rows and columns then iterate N times and take each row as input initially its stored as string but **map(int,)** makes each element  into integer

```py
R = int(input("Enter total Rows: "))
C = int(input("Enter total Columns: "))
matrix = [list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(R)]
print(matrix)
```

Input

```
Enter total Rows: 3
Enter total Columns: 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

When rows and cols are not given in online IDE it will throw EOF error you use input() when no input is given in such cases use

```
matrix = []
while True:
    try:
        matrix.append(list(map(int,input().split()))
    except:
        break
```